# How am I supposed to interpret this .cls code?

Tags: templates, document-classes

I am submitting a paper to a journal. In the .cls file the editors provide, the following code appears:

```
\gdef\@author{\mbox{}}
\def\author{\@ifnextchar [{\@authortwo}{\@authorone}}
\def\@authortwo[#1]#2{\gdef\@author{\uppercase{#2}}\gdef\@shortauthor{#1}}
\def\@authorone#1{\gdef\@author{#1}
\begingroup\gdef\@shortauthor{#1}\endgroup}
\def\shortauthor#1{\gdef\@shortauthor{#1}}
\gdef\@shortauthor{}
```

I am pretty sure it gives information on how to insert the authors of the paper. Let's say they are called John Haide Well and Maxwell John Baide. How should I write this in my .tex file?

Comment: Here's a guess: `\author[JH Well and MJ Baide]{John Haide Well and Maxwell John Baide}` that will be set when you issue `\maketitle`.

Comment: I doubt this is really the means of giving information about how to specify the authors. It is, rather, the implementation. Usually, there should be some documentation or an example or something. Also, you really should say where code is from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Line by line commentary

```
\gdef\@author{\mbox{}}
```

Initialize `\@author` to an empty box

```
\def\author{\@ifnextchar [{\@authortwo}{\@authorone}}
```

Define `\author` (the user level command) to execute `\@authortwo` if followed by `[`, `\@authorone` otherwise.

```
\def\@authortwo[#1]#2{\gdef\@author{\uppercase{#2}}\gdef\@shortauthor{#1}}
```

Define `\@authortwo` to absorb input of the form `\author[x]{y}` (we know `[` is there; store the bracket-delimited argument into `\@shortauthor` and the normal argument in `\@author` but surrounded by `\uppercase` (programming error here).

```
\def\@authorone#1{\gdef\@author{#1}
\begingroup\gdef\@shortauthor{#1}\endgroup}
```

Define `\@authorone` to store its argument in `\@author` and also store it in `\@shortauthor`. Why is the latter command done inside a group is something only the code author can explain. Also, why in only one case the author name is uppercased is a big mystery.

```
\def\shortauthor#1{\gdef\@shortauthor{#1}}
\gdef\@shortauthor{}
```

A user level command for storing the short author name in `\@shortauthor`; the variable is initialized to empty.

### Example 1

```
\author{Abigail Uthor}
```

We end up with `\@author` and `\@shortauthor` both containing `Abigail Uthor`

### Example 2

```
\author[A. Uthor]{Abigail Uthor}
```

We end up with `\@author` containing `\uppercase{Abigail Uthor}` and `\@shortauthor` containing `A. Uthor`

### Example 3

```
\author{Abigail Uthor}
\shortauthor{A. Uthor}
```

Like in example 2, but without the `\uppercase`.

### Example 4

```
\shortauthor{A. Uthor}
\author{Abigail Uthor}
```

Like in example 1, because the redefinition of `\@shortauthor` by `\shortauthor` is overridden by the code in `\author`

### Why is `\uppercase` a programming error?

Obviously, the different behavior when the optional argument is used is an error. However uppercasing should be done when `\@author` is *used*, not when it is stored. And `\MakeUppercase` should be used, anyway.